# Find the exponential Fourier coefficients

Tags: fourier

I am confused as to what the periodic function, Vin, is! I know the slope is 2/pi, but what about the vertical line? I am also unsure about its relation to Vo.

[image]

Comment: Google "sawtooth function".

Comment: Your question looks very much like homework. In general, homework questions
enjoy/suffer a special treatment.
We don't provide complete answers, we only provide hints or Socratic
questions and only when you have demonstrated sufficient effort of your
own, which you have not I am afraid. Otherwise, we would be doing you a
disservice, and getting swamped by homework questions at the same time.
Please revise your question showing your work and
findings so far, in considerable detail.
See also [here](http://meta.electronics.stackexchange.com/a/5120/7036)

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure whether my roughly calculated answer is correct or not,
so I'm not gonna post my calculating process to misguide you and embarrass myself.

So what I'll do is to share my concept on this exercise:

First,You'll need to understand the ***Exponential Fourier Series*** and ***Sawtooth wave*** and then you should have your `Vin(t)`.

Second,After having the exact equation or number of `Vin(t)`,then you'll need to know
the laws of circuit analysis or/and methods and know the components.

Third and last,After doing some work,you should have some answers,usually after very long math calculating process.

Or if you could sorting some equations then use Wolfram to skip some process,just saying...

Pretty much all mentioned above are able to find a lots of great resources on Google and YouTube,And all you have to is to combine all the pieces of information.

The answer is not the important thing,the most important is the what you've learnt during the process.

Best regards.